# laravel cashier braintree expiry date

Tags: laravel-5.5, braintree, laravel-cashier

I am using `"laravel/cashier-braintree": "~2.0"` package to manage subscriptions in my `Laravel 5.5.40` application.

So far i have created a plan to and created subscriptions to the plans via multiple users. I just cant find a way to get the plan expiry date for a user.

Based on this [laracast discussion](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-cashier-expiry-date?page=0), the ends_at column in `subscriptions` table stays null by default until a user cancels the subscription.

I did try the `Customer::find($braintree_id)` method and got a huge customer detail object with a `subscriptions` object as below:

```
"subscriptions": [
      {
        "addOns": [],
        "balance": "0.00",
        "billingDayOfMonth": 20,
        "billingPeriodEndDate": {
          "date": "2018-09-19 00:00:00.000000",
          "timezone_type": 3,
          "timezone": "UTC"
        },
        "billingPeriodStartDate": {
          "date": "2018-06-20 00:00:00.000000",
          "timezone_type": 3,
          "timezone": "UTC"
        },
        "createdAt": {
          "date": "2018-06-20 10:06:42.000000",
          "timezone_type": 3,
          "timezone": "UTC"
        },
        "updatedAt": {
          "date": "2018-06-21 05:56:43.000000",
          "timezone_type": 3,
          "timezone": "UTC"
        },
        "currentBillingCycle": 1,
        "daysPastDue": null,
        "discounts": [],
        "failureCount": 0,
        "firstBillingDate": {
          "date": "2018-06-20 00:00:00.000000",
          "timezone_type": 3,
          "timezone": "UTC"
        },
```

So is there any better way to get the plan subscription expiry date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Right now the [subscription response object](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/subscription/php) does not contain an attribute returned regarding the end date for a subscription. You can subtract the [`currentBillingCycle`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/subscription/php#current_billing_cycle) from the [`numberOfBillingCycles`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/subscription/php#number_of_billing_cycles) to find out when the subscription is set to end. I recommend first checking to see whether [`neverExpires`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/subscription/php#never_expires) returns as `true` to see if there is an end date.

For example, if the `numberOfBillingCycles` has a value of `12` and the `currentBillingCycle` is `4`, the number of billing cycles remaining is `8`.